# coremltools: how to properly use NeuralNetworkMultiArrayShapeRange?

Tags: python, pytorch, coreml, coremltools

I have a PyTorch network and I want to deploy it to iOS devices. In short, I fail to add flexibility to the input tensor shape in CoreML.

The network is a convnet that takes an RGB image (stored as a tensor) as an input and returns an RGB image of the same size. Using PyTorch, I can input images of any size I want, for instance a tensor of size (1, 3, 300, 300) for a 300x300 image.

To convert the PyTorch model to a CoreML model, I first convert it to an ONNX model using `torch.onnx.export`. This function requires to pass a dummy input so that it can execute the graph. So I did using:

```
input = torch.rand(1, 3, 300, 300)
```

My guess is that the ONNX model only accepts images / tensors of size (1, 3, 300, 300). Now, I can use the `onnx_coreml.convert` function to convert the ONNX model to a CoreML model. By printing the CoreML model's spec description using Python, I get something like:

```
input {
  name: "my_image"
  type {
    multiArrayType {
      shape: 1
      shape: 3
      shape: 300
      shape: 300
      dataType: FLOAT32
    }
  }
}
output {
  name: "my_output"
  type {
    multiArrayType {
      shape: 1
      shape: 3
      shape: 300
      shape: 300
      dataType: FLOAT32
    }
  }
}
metadata {
  userDefined {
    key: "coremltoolsVersion"
    value: "3.1"
  }
}
```

The model's input must be a `multiArrayType` of size (1, 3, 300, 300). By copying this model to XCode, I can see while inspecting the model that `my_name` is listed under the "Inputs" section and it is expected to be a `MultiArray (Float32 1 x 3 x 300 x 300)`. So far, everything is coherent.

My problem is to add flexibility to the input shape. I tried to use coremltools with no luck. This is my problem. Here is my code:

```
import coremltools
from coremltools.models.neural_network import flexible_shape_utils

spec = coremltools.utils.load_spec('my_model.mlmodel')

shape_range = flexible_shape_utils.NeuralNetworkMultiArrayShapeRange()
shape_range.add_channel_range((3,3))
shape_range.add_height_range((64, 5000))
shape_range.add_width_range((64, 5000))
flexible_shape_utils.update_multiarray_shape_range(spec, feature_name='my_image', shape_range=shape_range)
coremltools.models.utils.save_spec(spec, 'my_flexible_model.mlmodel')
```

I get the following spec description using Python:

```
input {
  name: "my_image"
  type {
    multiArrayType {
      shape: 1
      shape: 3
      shape: 300
      shape: 300
      dataType: FLOAT32
      shapeRange {
        sizeRanges {
          lowerBound: 3
          upperBound: 3
        }
        sizeRanges {
          lowerBound: 64
          upperBound: 5000
        }
        sizeRanges {
          lowerBound: 64
          upperBound: 5000
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Only 3 ranges as specified, which makes sense since I only defined a range for channel, height and width, but not for the batch size. In XCode, I get the following error when inspecting the flexible CoreML model:

```
There was a problem decoding this CoreML document
validator error: Description of multiarray feature 'my_image' has a default 4-d shape but a 3-d shape range
```

I'm pretty sure it was working on another project when I was on macOS X Mojave, but at this point I'm sure of nothing.

I'm using:

- macOS X Catalina
- conda 4.7.12
- python 3.7.5
- pytorch 1.3.1
- onnx 1.6.0
- onnx-coreml 1.1
- coremltools 3.1

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is to remove that `shape:1`. Something like this:

```
del spec.description.input[0].shape[0]
```

Now the default shape should also have 3 dimensions.

However, I would suggest changing the type of the input from multi-array to an actual image. Since you're going to be using it with images anyway. That will let you pass in the image as a `CVPixelBuffer` or `CGImage` object instead of an `MLMultiArray`.

Comment: Using `del spec.description.input[0].type.multiArrayType.shape[0]` I was able to get rid of the first dimension as you proposed, and then I was able to add flexibility. However, I was not able to call the predict function using coremltools (Unable to load CoreML.framework. Cannot make predictions.) and XCode displayed an error in the model description window (validator error: Layer '88' of type 'Convolution' has input rank 3 but expects rank at least 4.).
The problem probably comes from the extrem layers that are unconventionnal. I'll try to switch to images as you proposed.

Comment: Can you load the model into Xcode without the flexible inputs? It's strange that you'd get an error on a convolution layer just because you've added input flexibility.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was not clear.
1) I can load the initial CoreML model in XCode but I cannot add flexibility to it (since the input is a 4D tensor).
2) By removing the first dimension using `del (...)`, I can add flexibility to the model, but then I cannot load the model with or without flexibility in XCode (`validator error: Layer '88' of type 'Convolution' has input rank 3 but expects rank at least 4.`)

Comment: It's hard to debug this from a distance, but does it work when you leave the `shape: 1` in there and add a 4-th `sizeRanges` thing with `lowerBound: 1` and `upperBound: -1`? You can't use NeuralNetworkMultiArrayShapeRange for this I think, so you'll have to modify the `shapeRange` directly using the protobuf objects. Not sure if Core ML will like having 4 dimensions there instead of 3, but worth trying.

Comment: I think adding `sizeRanges` manually could solve my problem. I've tried on a subpart of my model and it looks promising. I now have to validate this on the main model. Will comment here as soon as I have new information.

Comment: I think I understand the problem. My PyTorch model has 3 parts: downsampling -> convnet -> upsampling (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177052). If I remove the custom downsampling / upsampling parts, I can manually add flexibility using `sizeRanges` to the 4D input tensor. With coremltools, CoreML deduces the output shape from the input shape and the inference is working fine. When I put back the downsampling / upsampling parts, the output shape computed by CoreML does not change to reflect the input shape. My guess is that my custom dowsampling / upsampling functions are to blame.